# How to find two nondecreasing functions $f$ and $g$ such that $(\alpha x - \beta y)(f(x) - g(y)) \ge 0$?

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-inequalities

I'm trying to find two nondecreasing functions $f$ and $g$ such that
$$(\alpha x - \beta y)(f(x) - g(y)) \ge 0$$
for every $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$ and arbitrary constants $\alpha >0$ and $\beta > 0$. The functions $f$ and $g$ can equal ($f=g$), if it helps, but $f$ and $g$ cannot explicitly contain $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

It is obviously true that $(\alpha x - \beta y)(f(\alpha x) - f(\beta y)) \ge 0$ for any $f$ nondecreasing, but this is exactly what I don't want.

Maybe there is a trivial solution but I can't see it. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ both identically $0$ would trivially work if the inequality sign is $\ge$.

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth Right.Thanks!  Any idea how to find nontrivial solution to the problem?

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary, that sounds a lot like the above inequality must be true for all $\alpha,\beta$. That can't work with non-trivial examples: If $f(x) \neq g(y)$ for any $x,y>0$, then you can choose $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha x - \beta y$ has any sign you want.

Comment: @ Ingix Thank you for your reply. I was almost sure that the answer is negative.